# PHP variable resets/not available after jquery load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using jquery .load() to show a php file that basically fetch data from a table. Inside the while loop, I have a variable which checks my user's ranks, however, on every .load() this variable seem to become unavailable and everything in the if statement containing that variable, disappears.

Now I am aware of this:

- PHP runs before any browser response is issued to the client, and all
  code runs on the server. The variables declared in your PHP file are
  destroyed after all the PHP code has been run; they "vanish."
- JavaScript runs after the browser response has begun, and all code
  runs on the client. By "loading" the output result of the PHP file,
  you won't get any access to PHP's variables, only the output.

However, how am I supposed to access my variable this way?

This is the line that disappears after .load()

```
<div id="deleteSB">
    <?php if($u_rank >= 2) { 
        ?>    
        <div style="float: left;margin-top:3px;margin-right:5px;" id="deletesb">
        <a href="<?php echo $siteurl;?>/forum?getDelSb=<?php echo $fetchshoutquer['id']; ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>/img/delete.png" /></a></div>    
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Where `$u_rank` is the variable that I need. If I remove that if statement, everything works fine.

This is the jQuery:

```
function loadlink(){
        $('#loadshoutbox').load('http://localhost/shoutboxcontent.php');

    }

    function loadlink2(){
        $('#shoutboxinput').load('http://localhost/shoutboxinput.php');
    }

    loadlink(); // This will run on page load
    loadlink2();
    setInterval(function(){
        loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
    }, 5000);
    setInterval(function(){
        loadlink2() // this will run after every 60 seconds
    }, 60000);
```

I thought of storing the contents of `$u_rank` in a jQuery variable, but then I don't know how to do with the if statement...

Comment: I'm still reading, but I don't think you can just load in a php script and expect it to work.  PHP runs before the page does, so loading in a PHP page will just act blank, correct?  You need to do an AJAX call if you want to get PHP variables into your script

Comment: Works fine so far. And I use AJAX to insert new data into the database. I'm just having trouble with that one variable not being available after load()...

Comment: Yeah, I just don't think you can just load in a variable like that, you need another AJAX call to bring it back.  Or, if you want that variable directly after your AJAX call when inserting data, just echo it on the same script and return the data like the answer below

Comment: "This is the line that disappears after .load()" After which load-statement?

Comment: It's the setinterval for loadlink();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I guess you're looking for sessions then.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: I can't see any difference between using a normal variable and a session... that session variable would also disappear?

Comment: No, session variables stay when the page gets reloaded. Not when the browser is closed ofcourse. Then i'd look into cookies.

Comment: Okay, I can't believe this actually worked... thanks! Seem to be the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for a `$.post`, or AJAX call

```
$.post('script.php', {variableIn:variableIn}, function(data){
    var u_rank = data;
});
```

You need to call the PHP again to grab that variable from the PHP script.   This is extremely simplified of course and you'll need to figure out what data you're bringing back.  You can return anything echoed from the PHP script using that `data`.

For example. when I return a few results from my PHP script:

```
echo $var1 . ":" . $var2;
```

`data` will return "variable1:variable2".  Then I use split in my AJAX call like so:

```
$.post('script.php', {variableIn:variableIn}, function(data){
    var var1 = data.split(":")[0];
    var var2 = data.split(":")[1];
});
```

Comment: No, javascript would interpret that as a string (and would need quotes).  The page would have already run the PHP at that point, so basically PHP would not be allowed after that.

Comment: Thanks. I will keep experimenting with your method!

Comment: you got it! Let me know if you have problems with that